# VS2017 Community - Page is not supported in a windows universal project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Beginner here working through John Sharp's C# step by step book and for whatever reason the solution 'MathsOperators' is showing the error "VS2017 Page is not supported in a Windows Universal project", 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzywl.png).

[I saw the exact same question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686433/vs2017-page-is-not-supported-in-a-windows-universal-project) but updating I updated my NuGet package and restarted both VS and my machine without success.

[If helpful the solution downloads are listed here](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/microsoft-visual-c-sharp-step-by-step-9781509301041#downloads)

Comment: I downloaded the code. Unzipped it, found the project folder and opened it. It upgraded the target version, then briefly showed similar to your screenshot but once the project was built it worked fine. Have you had this issue with any of the other example projects?

Comment: I haven't encountered this error yet but I did just update some things in VS so maybe that's causing the issue? I should clarify, the solution works if I debug so I think the issue is only with the xaml linting?

Comment: Is upgrading the target version something that you need to do or does that happen automatically?

Comment: So very frustrating. I was thoroughly enjoying the book but my progress has hit a dead stop...

Comment: Upgrading happens automatically when initially opening the project. I imagine the project was created under an older version of Visual Studio prior to 2017.

Comment: The author's note states: 
_italic_All the exercises and code samples in this book have been developed and tested using VS community 2017. They should all work, unchanged, in VS professional 2017 and VS Enterprise 2017_italic_

Comment: I'm uninstalling VS and reinstalling, hoping that will work.

Comment: Wait. I just unzipped it again and it was retargeting the framework, not upgrading the project. I don't have 10240 SDK installed, so I had to select one of the newer ones that I do have installed.

Comment: It was too late, I had already started the uninstall. I'm reinstalling now and then I will try what you said.

Comment: OK. Hopefully it doesn't need to download everything again. If it's still not working after reinstalling let me know.

Comment: The question now becomes, how does one know if they need to retarget the framework and, if needed, how does one retarget framework?

Comment: The project stores the framework version that's targeted when last built. If you don't have the SDK installed on your machine - it's part of the installer for VS then it forces you to select a version that you have installed. Also, when building the project you select a framework that matches the user base you want to support with features since older frameworks may not include some feature you want to use in your project, effectively limiting you to a minimum supported version. This is visible in Project > [YourProjectName] Properties > Targeting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the solution file from my directory, reinstalled it, then opened with VS. This time I was prompted like fourwhey said and able to update the target. Once the solution opened I no longer had the page is not supported errors but I did have a 'some assembly references are missing' error in my design window but building the solution resolved that.

That was harder than it needed to be.